# How does method timezone getOffset uses date on PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone-offset

I'm trying to understand how PHP uses the given datetime to return `getOffset` result on a DateTimeZone object. As far as I see,  the result is always the same no matter what datetime I pass.

```
public function testGetOffset()
{
    // UTC offset is 00:00 (0 seconds)
    $timeZoneUtc = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
    $dateUTC = new \DateTime('now', $timeZoneUtc);

    // America/Sao_Paulo offset is -02:00 (-7200 seconds)
    $timeZoneSP = new \DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $dateSP = new \DateTime('now', $timeZoneSP);

    // America/New_York offset is -05:00 (-18000 seconds)
    $timeZoneNY = new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
    $dateNY = new \DateTime('now', $timeZoneNY);


    $this->assertEquals(0, $timeZoneUtc->getOffset($dateUTC)); // true
    $this->assertEquals(0, $timeZoneUtc->getOffset($dateNY));  // true
    $this->assertEquals(0, $timeZoneUtc->getOffset($dateSP));  // true


    $this->assertEquals(-7200, $timeZoneSP->getOffset($dateUTC)); // true
    $this->assertEquals(-7200, $timeZoneSP->getOffset($dateNY));  // true
    $this->assertEquals(-7200, $timeZoneSP->getOffset($dateSP));  // true


    $this->assertEquals(-18000, $timeZoneNY->getOffset($dateUTC)); // true
    $this->assertEquals(-18000, $timeZoneNY->getOffset($dateNY));  // true
    $this->assertEquals(-18000, $timeZoneNY->getOffset($dateSP));  // true
}
```

Can anyone help me get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offset changes only during a [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) transition. New York will transition from winter time to summer time on March 11. `getOffset` tells you what the offset for that timezone is at that particular time. All the times you're giving it are all today, well before the DST transition date, so they all result in the same offset. Try getting the offset for a date before and after March 11 to see a difference.

Answer (score 1):

A date is an absolute moment in time, it doesn't depend on a timezone. The timezone is used only when the date is formatted as string.

Internally, all three `DateTime` objects created by the code store the same value: the number of seconds (and microseconds on PHP 7) since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.